# Functions with same name, different origin

Tags: c++, function, header, namespaces

I am writing a function in a class which shares the same name with another function originating in a header file (specifically socket.h).

```
void XClass::bind(){
     //...
     int rv = bind(listener, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(sockaddr));

}
```

Of course, bind(..) is calling the function in the class and not the one from the header (implicitly the code is uncompilable).

Since it is not located in a namespace declaration, would it be possible to call the *right* method? If affirmative, how?

I am aware that I could redeclare it differently, however if I have large chunks of code containing external functions of which names coincide with the caller itself, consequent renaming sounds like nightmare.

Comment: Simply use a replace all option

Comment: @Taimours I am clearly aware of the primitive options AND I am not looking to rename declarations -- to dissect a specific situation, that does not 'work' that well (if not at all) when you are writing the program as an external dependency

Comment: ok, so you are trying to find a way to do this without replace all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend the relevant name with `::` to signify that you're looking it up in the global namespace:

```
int rv = ::bind(listener, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(sockaddr));
```

Comment: I was expecting something similar - like a "global" op (ref. c#'s global:: ); seems intuitive enough though